# Differential geometry unit vector

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, general-relativity

Why is $$e_\mu=\partial_\mu$$always said to be the unit vector ?

Doesn't the size of the vector $\partial_\mu$ kindoff depend on the underlying manifold ?

Comment: Yes you are right. I dont see why $\partial_\mu$ is a unit vector. But for example when you are in a normal coordinate at one point $p\in M$, then $\partial_\mu$ really has unit length at that point.

Comment: You would say $\partial_\mu$ is unit if the underlying manifold is euclidean space. So you should say the same thing for manifolds because every manifold is infinitesimally euclidean.

Comment: @Mud, no that's not right. Only for flat Riemannian manifolds can you arrange that.

Comment: Ok, thanks now I at least don't feel totally crazy :p. This question came to me when I was looking at differential operators (see edit in the making), where they do claim to use the unit vectors.

Comment: Never mind, I'm mixing up a (bad) physics differential-geometry course with a real differential-geometry course ... . But just to be sure, when I calculate the divergence $\nabla_\mu V^\mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_\mu(\sqrt{|g|}V^\mu)$. $V^\mu$ is defined wrt to the basis $\partial_\mu$ and not the unit-basis, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Riemannian manifold with metric $g$ the length-squared of $\partial_{\mu}$ would be $g(\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\mu})$. Why should this be one?

It is possible to choose an orthonormal frame by rescaling a coordinate frame at a point. However, it is generally not possible to orthonormalize a coordinate frame over some open set in the manifold (unless of course, the thing is flat...)

Comment: Yes, I found where my confusion came from, I compared (see my last comment). It that last statement correct you think ? (just to be sure I'm nog completely mixing up everyting).

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure why to look at divergence here, I mean, yes it's manifold theoretic formulation may be given in terms of a metric formulation ( I think your formula is correct ), but, the reason you can pick an orthonormal frame at a point is simply that $g$ gives an inner product on the tangent space at that point. So, you can apply the Gram-Schmidt procedure to form an orthonormal basis at $p$. Moreover, you can choose coordinates which produce those vectors as coordinate derivations at that point. The trouble is, you can't find a coordinate system which stays orthonormal away from the..

Comment: point. If it were possible then that would imply trivial Christoffel symbols and hence vanishing curvature. This said, we can pick non-coordinate frames which are orthonormal over some open set. Their connection coefficients are non-trivial in general and the extent of that non-triviality measures the existence of curvature in the space. It also has to do with covariant differentiation, parallel transport etc... I feel your pain with the physics differential geometry. It's rough over there sometimes, but, ask questions here, there are many who will help!

Comment: that's exactly what I'm doing ;). I also started reading Frankel's book (don't know if that's advised, but it seems legit). And the divergence was just another check for myself. I'm not always sur in which case they use unit-vectors $e_\mu$ and basis-vectors $\partial_\mu$. This is something that's not always easy to see for me :(.

Comment: @Nick hey, I wanted to urge you to look at Sean Carrol's text if you haven't already. I used to have a a copy (I still have no idea who I lent it to... so annoying...) and it might be a good fit for some of your questions... it's an expansion of the notes found here http://preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/

Comment: thanks! Yes I've already studied it for a course on general relativity. But also there they are sometimes a little bit unclear in if they use $\partial_\mu$ of $e_\mu$ :(.